# libphonenumber ios get country code for country

Tags: ios, objective-c, libphonenumber

Given a country, how do I get the countryCode? The following method is not working

```
NSNumber* code = [phoneUtil getCountryCodeForRegion:country];
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'the method doesn't work'? What is the return value?

Comment: There are not very many country codes and they very rarely change. You can find all of them on Wikipedia or in the unicode CLDR

Comment: @Katedral Hi I want to get the country code of country from the given phone number. So can you please help that how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It is working, I used it like so:

```
[phoneUtil getCountryCodeForRegion:@"US"]
```

and the output was 1.

**Note** that you have to use the ISO Country Code, 2 Digit: "US", (you can find a list [here](http://countrycode.org/)).