# How to get a country code from the given phone number

Tags: ios, phone-number

I have two phone numbers +17896786788 and +322657579849. I would like to retrieve only the code I.e, +1 and +322 by passing these phone number.

Is there any API avalable to get the code out of phone number?

libphonenumber gives the country code for the given country. Link: [libphonenumber ios get country code for country](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25879186/libphonenumber-ios-get-country-code-for-country)

But I would like to get the code out of phone number.

Comment: Specifically, read [THIS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCarrier/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CTCarrier/isoCountryCode)

Comment: The above link provides the country code from the carrier network.              But i wanted the country code from the specified phone number. Please do not mark it as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a long time investigating this, and so far there is no way to do this on iOS.

Sure we can make a guess, and it would work in most cases, but there is always some cases where it will be difficult, let me give you a few exemples:

- Canada and USA share the same international prefix: +1
- Martinique is part of France, but has its own international prefix: +596
- Taiwan can be considered part of China or not depending on the user's interpretation

And the list goes on..